# How to read .jks file into Kubernetes secret?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, truststore, kubernetes-secrets

I have created a secret.yaml file as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  truststore.jks: {{ (.Files.Glob "../trust.jks").AsSecrets | b64enc }}
```

I am calling this as part of template .yaml file in HELM.

.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
spec:
...
template:
  spec:
  ...
  container:
   - name: "my-container"
     ...
     volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets
          mountPath: /mnt/secrets
          readOnly: true

 volumes:
    - name: secrets
      secret:
        secretName: "my-secret"
```

When I run helm install command the pod gets created successfully, and the volume is also mounted, but if I check the `truststore.jks` in /mnt/secrets using cat command below is the output:

```
cat /mnt/secrets/truststore.jks
{}
```

I ran the dry run command to check the generated .yaml file, the secret is populted as below:

```
# Source: ag-saas/templates/tsSecret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  truststore.jks: e30=
```

How do I get the file into my secret?

Comment: I did go through the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423398/what-is-a-good-way-to-deploy-secret-java-key-stores-in-an-openshift-environment, but here the contents of the .jks file is manually copied into the data. I need data  to be populated from the file while the secrete is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here:

- `.Files.Glob` is intended to retrieve multiple files, *e.g.* `.Files.Glob "credentials/*.jks"`.  For a single file `.File.Get` will retrieve its contents directly.
- You can only access files inside the chart directory; referencing `.Files.Get "../trust.jks"` won't work.
- `.Files.Glob.AsSecret` renders a list of files to the entire contents of the `data:` block; you just directly need the file content.

So your Secret should look like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  truststore.jks: {{ .Files.Get "trust.jks" | b64enc }}
```

where in the last line I've used `.Files.Get`, I've not tried to refer to a `"../..."` path outside the chart, and I don't render it to `...AsSecret`.

You also will need to move or copy (not symlink) the keyset file into the chart directory for this to work.

(In the current form, `.Files.Glob` won't match anything outside the chart directory, so you get an empty list of files.  Then rendering that to `.AsSecrets` gets you an empty JSON object.  You're using that string `{}` as the secret value, which gets correctly base64-encoded, but that's why `{}` comes out at the end.)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. A follow up question, Inhad my .jks file file inside the Charts directory and the secret config file in the templates directory. So why did it not read when I referenced it as ../trust.jks?

Comment: The paths used by `.Files.Get` (and `.Files.Glob`) are relative to the top-level chart directory, not the location of the template file.